# Entity Framework migration ignoring some enums

Tags: entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-migrations

First of all, we are using .NET 4.5, so this shouldn't be an issue.

I've got six classes with enum properties, however when I create the migration, for some reason it's ignoring the enum properties on two of the classes, but not the others!

For example, this class:

```
public class CreditCardForeignUsage : EntityBase
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual CreditCard CreditCard { get; set; }
    public int CreditCardId { get; set; }

    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public ForeignUsageNetwork? Network { get; set; }
    public ForeignUsageLocation? Location { get; set; }
    public decimal? Percent { get; set; }
    public bool? ManuallyAdded { get; set; }
}
```

Generates the following migration code (all fine):

```
            CreateTable(
            "dbo.CreditCardForeignUsage",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    CreditCardId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Active = c.Boolean(),
                    Network = c.Int(),
                    Location = c.Int(),
                    Percent = c.Decimal(precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    ManuallyAdded = c.Boolean(),
                    Timestamp = c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"),
                    Created = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.CreditCard", t => t.CreditCardId)
            .Index(t => t.CreditCardId);
```

But this class:

```
public class CreditCardRate : EntityBase
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual CreditCard CreditCard { get; set; }
    public int CreditCardId { get; set; }

    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public RateType? RateType { get; set; }
    public int? MinBalance { get; set; }
    public int? MaxBalance { get; set; }
    public int? RatePeriod { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RateDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? MonthlyRate { get; set; }
    public YearlyRateType? YearlyRateType { get; set; }
    public decimal? YearlyRate { get; set; }
    public bool? ManuallyAdded { get; set; }
}
```

Generates this (RateType and YearlyRateType are missing):

```
            CreateTable(
            "dbo.CreditCardRate",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    CreditCardId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Active = c.Boolean(),
                    MinBalance = c.Int(),
                    MaxBalance = c.Int(),
                    RatePeriod = c.Int(),
                    RateDate = c.DateTime(),
                    MonthlyRate = c.Decimal(precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    YearlyRate = c.Decimal(precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    ManuallyAdded = c.Boolean(),
                    Timestamp = c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"),
                    Created = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.CreditCard", t => t.CreditCardId)
            .Index(t => t.CreditCardId);
```

Any ideas? Is this a bug of some sort?

**EDIT**

Enums are declared as follows:

```
namespace CE.Core.Portal.DTOs.CreditCards
{
    public enum RateType
    {
        StandardDirectDebit = 1,
        StandardPurchases = 2,
        StandardCash = 3,
        StandardOther = 4,
        IntroPurchases = 5,
        BalanceTransfer = 6,
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the enums being ignored nested enums (i.e. do they live inside another type (class)? What is the underlying type for those enum types? Can you show how they are defined?

Comment: Nope, they're all declared publicly in the namespace. I just noticed though that we're using EF 4.0, with .Net 4.5. Although that still doesn't really explain why it's working on some classes, and not others.

Comment: *First of all, we are using .NET 4.5, so this shouldn't be an issue.* Considering support for enums was added in EF5 and not the .NET Framework 4.5, you might want to re-consider how much of an issue this will be.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, we ARE using EF 5. (sorry, I was looking at the runtime version :P)

Comment: @ta.speot.is - enums were added in EF5 component that lived in .NET Framework so you have to have .NET Framework 4.5 to be able to use enums with EF. EF5 for .NET Framework 4 does not support enums.

Comment: We are using .NET 4.5 :) Oddly, I have another class that references one of the "problem" enums, and it's working on that. This must be a bug, so I think I'll just declare the problem ones as ints.

Comment: Tom, I just ran into this question and tried to repro using the code snippets you provided, but I couldn't see any issue. Did you ever find out what was going on? Otherwise could you provide a full repro?

Comment: Hi divega, apologies for the late response. I just came across the issue again (in some other code), however I tried renaming the property to the same name as the Enum and it was no longer ignored. Just thought I'd mention it in case you or anyone else sees this.